# Unicode UTF-8 at VBA

Tags: vba, csv, utf-8

I have this VBA code to convert CSV to XLSX, which seems to work but output Excel have strange strings like "AÃ§o" and "plÃ¡stico" instead of "Aço" or "plástico". I think solution is to include "Unicode UTF-8", but I couldn't find a way. Any help would be appreciated.

```vb
Sub CSVtoXLSX()

    Dim xFd As FileDialog
    Dim xSPath As String
    Dim xCSVFile As String
    Dim xWsheet As String

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.StatusBar = True
    xWsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Set xFd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFd.Title = "Select a folder:"
    If xFd.Show = -1 Then
        xSPath = xFd.SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Right(xSPath, 1) <> "\" Then xSPath = xSPath + "\"
    xCSVFile = Dir(xSPath & "*.csv")
    Do While xCSVFile <> ""
        Application.StatusBar = "Converting: " & xCSVFile
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=xSPath & xCSVFile
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Replace(xSPath & xCSVFile, ".csv", ".xlsx", vbTextCompare), xlWorkbookDefault
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        Windows(xWsheet).Activate
        xCSVFile = Dir
    Loop
    Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Take a look [at this solution](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/644617-opening-unicode-csv-file-vba.html)

Comment: Open the source .csv file with Notepad++ and check what is the file encoding (at the lower right corner of the window).